# Can you find function by type signature in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm looking for utility similar to one of Hoogle for Haskell. For the sake of example, let's say I need a function of signature `forall n m:nat, n <> m -> m <> n`.

When my Google searches don't yield any results, I write `Definition foo: forall n m:nat, n <> m -> m <> n.` and write `intros; auto with arith.` to prove it. But is there any way to not pollute my workspace with these temporary results and search for them based on their type? I'm sure I've seen this symmetry stated somewhere in standard library.

Answer (score 6):

There's a `Search` command that's somewhat similar to Hoogle, but a bit more precise. Here are some searches you might use for symmetry of not. In practice I would use the first and fall back to the second if there were a lot of results.

```
Search (_ <> _). (* everything related to not equal *)
Search (?a <> ?b -> ?b <> ?a). (* exactly what you want -
    note that unlike Hoogle, you need to use ?a for a pattern variable *)
Search (?R ?a ?b -> ?R ?b ?a). (* this searches for any symmetry theorem;
    not terribly useful for it's cool that it works *)
Search not "_sym". (* if you know some of the theorem name you can use that, too *)
```

Comment: FWIW, `Search` (unlike Hoogle) looks only inside current environment. So it won't help one find lemmas/functions if they are in an unimported library.